# How to Compare PHP variables?

Tags: php

How to compare php value?

In my code the else part value is : **undefined**

Why is **$final = $filename;** value is undefined?

```
$imgsname = $_POST['imgsname'];
$filename = $_POST['filename'];

if ($imgsname != "") {
    $final = $imgsname;
} else {
    $final = $filename;
}

echo $final;
```

Comment: use - isset($imgsname) instead of $imgsname != ""

Comment: Are your form elements named? Plus this `$_POST['filename']` should probably be `$_FILES['filename']` maybe even the same for `$_POST['imgsname']` since we're most likely dealing with (uploaded) files and not text etc. Therefore, it's hard to give you a definite answer. Show your full code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In light of missing code, I'm certain that we're dealing with **files** instead of other types of form elements; text, checkbox etc.

Doing this

```
<?php 

$_POST['imgsname'] = "images name"; // comment or delete to test

$_POST['filename'] = "filename";

$imgsname = $_POST['imgsname'];
$filename = $_POST['filename'];

if ($imgsname != "") {
    $final = $imgsname;
} else {
    $final = $filename;
}

echo $final;
```

TEST:

If you delete or comment out `$_POST['imgsname'] = "images name";` you will see that there will be a different message.

Therefore, and more than likely, change (all) `$_POST` to `$_FILES` accordingly and make sure that your form elements are named with no typos, including the proper enctype and post method.